# put custom width,height and disable sizing

Tags: user-interface, kotlin, tornadofx

How to lock sizing with a custom form size using tornadofx?

```
class MainView : View("Form") {
override val root = form{
    fieldset("Personal Information") {
        field("ID") {
            textfield()
        }
        field("Password") {
            textfield()
        }
        field {
            button("Login")
            button("Register")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to constrain the actual form size, or constrain a field inside a fieldset?

Comment: @EdvinSyse actual form size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form layout supports prefSize like most containers. Add this inside of the form builder, before the fieldset declaration:

```
setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)
```

A Node cannot express that the window shouldn't be resizeable though, so this must be handled at the Window level. Some parent containers might honor `maxSize`, but this will not affect the ability to resize the window.